# removing multiple occurrence from csv in python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have CSV file from which I have to create another CSV in a particular format. I am sharing my input CSV and output CSV file(that I am getting with my code) and desired output CSV format. Please help me to achieve this.
Input sample File:

```
MSISDN,REQUEST_ID,STATE1,STATE2,STAETE3,NOTIFICATION
22969000034,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA
22969000034,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA
22969000034,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,NA,COMPLETED,Successfully send SMS to the subscriber
22969000035,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA
22969000035,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA
22969000035,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,NA,COMPLETED,Successfully send SMS to the subscriber
22969000036,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA
22969000036,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA
22969000037,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA
```

Output Sample Data:

```
('22969000034', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
('22969000034', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'NA', 'NA')
('22969000034', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'COMPLETED', 'Successfully send SMS to the subscriber')
('22969000035', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
('22969000035', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'NA', 'NA')
('22969000035', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'COMPLETED', 'Successfully send SMS to the subscriber')
('22969000036', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
('22969000036', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'NA', 'NA')
('22969000037', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
```

Required sample data:

```
('22969000034', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'COMPLETED', 'Successfully send SMS to the subscriber')
('22969000035', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'COMPLETED', 'Successfully send SMS to the subscriber')
('22969000036', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'IN_PROGRESS', 'NA', 'NA')
('22969000037', 'OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27', 'ENTERED', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA')
```

I am using below code:

```
with open('msLog.csv', 'r') as readfile:
    output = csv.DictReader(readfile)
    f_list = []
    msd = ''
    id = ''
    st1 = ''
    st2 = ''
    st3 = ''
    txt = ''
    for row in output:
        msd1 = row.get('MSISDN')
        if msd1 and row.get('STAETE3') != 'NA' and row.get('NOTIFICATION') != 'NA':
            msd = msd1
            id = row.get('REQUEST_ID')
            st3 = row.get('STAETE3')
            txt = row.get('NOTIFICATION')
        elif msd1 and row.get('STAETE3') == 'NA' and row.get('STATE1') =='NA':
            st2 = row.get('STATE2')
            id = row.get('REQUEST_ID')
            msd = msd1
            #st1 = 'NA'
            st3 = 'NA'
            txt = 'NA'
        elif msd1 and row.get('STAETE3') == 'NA' and row.get('STATE2') =='NA':
            st1 = row.get('STATE1')
            id = row.get('REQUEST_ID')
            msd = msd1
            st2 = 'NA'
            st3 = 'NA'
            txt = 'NA'
        print(msd,id,st1,st2,st3,txt)
```

Comment: Please tell what your problem, you just posted your required output but didn't tell how to get that output.

Answer (score 0):

Get up to speed using tabular data with pandas, it'll save you a lot of time. 
I pasted your data into a file called so.csv. You can then read that file into a pandas dataframe, group by MSISDN and take the last of each group, in two lines:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('Documents/so.csv',sep=',')
df.groupby('MSISDN').last()
Out[43]:
                                                    REQUEST_ID   STATE1       STATE2    STAETE3                             NOTIFICATION
MSISDN
22969000034  OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef...  ENTERED  IN_PROGRESS  COMPLETED  Successfully send SMS to the subscriber
22969000035  OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef...  ENTERED  IN_PROGRESS  COMPLETED  Successfully send SMS to the subscriber
22969000036  OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef...  ENTERED  IN_PROGRESS        NaN                                      NaN
22969000037  OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef...  ENTERED          NaN        NaN                                      NaN
```

Comment: i am using python 2.7 and there is no pandas module and i tried to install it but didn't get relevant module. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

Comment: did you try `pip install pandas` ? I encourage you to 'use the  free ferrari' rather than reinvent the wheel

Comment: i am getting error "pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file". I tried with comma as well as with \t sep. In both case i am getting same error.

Comment: are you sure you have a file with the correct name as what you are trying to read, in the right place?  All I did was copy-paste the text in the first part of your post into a text file with no formatting, and name it `so.csv` - it sounds like maybe your file is an empty file?

Answer (score 0):

Pure Python2.

Build a dictionary scanning the data for updated entries under the same ID, output the header and, ID by ID, the dictionary.

Note: I know that Python3 dicts respect the order of formation, I *think* that Python2 dicts, for Python2 recent enough, do the same but to be safe I used the `sorted` builtin to have the IDs sorted in *lexicographical* order, remove `sorted` or introduce a `key` function as you see fit…

```
$ cat na.py
from __future__ import print_function

data = '''MSISDN,REQUEST_ID,STATE1,STATE2,STATE3,NOTIFICATION 
22969000034,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA 
22969000034,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA 
22969000034,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,NA,COMPLETED,Successfully send SMS to the subscriber 
22969000035,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27 ,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA 
22969000035,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA 
22969000035,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,NA,COMPLETED,Successfully send SMS to the subscriber 
22969000036,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA 
22969000036,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,NA,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA 
22969000037,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA\
'''.split('\n') 

# alternatively, if data in external file, file=open(fname)
file = iter(data)

d = {}
header = next(file)

for data in ([tok.strip() for tok in line.split(',')] for line in file):
    id, rest = data[0], data[1:]
    if id in d:
        for n, (old, new) in enumerate(zip(d[id], rest)):
            if old == new: pass
            elif old != 'NA':
                rest[n] = old
    d[id] = rest

print(header)
for id, rest in sorted(d.items()): print(id, *rest, sep=',')
$ python2 na.py
MSISDN,REQUEST_ID,STATE1,STATE2,STATE3,NOTIFICATION 
22969000034,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,COMPLETED,Successfully send SMS to the subscriber
22969000035,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,COMPLETED,Successfully send SMS to the subscriber
22969000036,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,IN_PROGRESS,NA,NA
22969000037,OFFLINE_Notification_10.10.46.95_e6444dbc-b7ef-41d6-9111-eaa384717b27,ENTERED,NA,NA,NA
$
```